# botframework v4: ReplaceDialogAsync A dialog with an id of 'X' wasn't found

Tags: c#, .net, botframework

I have a working bot using a fixed waterfall flow and single dialog however I wish to expand the bot to have multiple different dialogs that will be switched between depending on user inputs. The dialogs I am using have been tested individually and work separate from each other. The first working dialog allows users to chose between 4 options which should then open different dialogs depending on the chosen option.

Within my currently working dialog I am attempting to switch to another dialog using the following line.

```
return await stepContext.ReplaceDialogAsync("QnaMakerQueryDialog");
```

The documentation for ReplaceDialogAsync states " Ends the active dialog and starts a new dialog in its place. This is particularly useful for creating loops or redirecting to another dialog." which sounds exactly like what I am trying to do however I get the error "A dialog with an id of 'QnaMakerQueryDialog' wasn't found." I would expect the Dialog to start from the begining of the QnaMakerQueryDialog however it simply throws the above error and continues within the current dialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to make an educated guess that the call to `ReplaceDialogAsync` that you show above is being made from within a `ComponentDialog`. Is that right?

If so, dialogs that are children of `ComponentDialogs` cannot invoke dialogs *outside of* that `ComponentDialog`. This is a limitation in the current version (currently 4.2) and a solution is being considered that would lift this restriction.

If this sounds like it matches your scenario, [please visit this issue in GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/5242) and upvote it to make your voice heard that this is something you'd like to see addressed in a future release.

Comment: Thank you I was unaware of this limitation. No to try think of a work around/new approach.

Comment: I can give you one, but it's FUGLY: hand in the `DialogSet` where the dialog you want to invoke lives to the constructor of your `ComponentDialog` and where you're calling `ReplaceDialogAsync` now, instead call `CreateContextAsync` on that `DialogSet`, then use the resulting `DialogContext` instance and call `ReplaceDialogAsync` via that.  It _should_ work, I'm so sorry I'm even suggesting this though. 

Comment: I checked the GitHub issue. They've marked it as resolved, saying they've implemented the capability now in ComponentDialogs but I was still not able to do it, I had to do it in a different type of dialog.

Comment: how? please share code.  thanks.